# Overflow error when trying to save a numpy array as an image using scipy.misc.imsave

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to view a 71290x71290 array of `numpy.float32`s. My computer runs out of memory when I try to use matplotlib to view it interactively, so I'm trying to save it as an image file and view it outside of ipython. The following should work, afaik from reading other SO posts:

```
import numpy as np
W = np.zeros((71290, 71290), dtype='float32')    
from scipy.misc import imsave
imsave('test.png', W)
```

But the last line gives me an overflow error:

> OverflowError: size does not fit in an int

Here's the full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/agittens/Documents/langmodel/<ipython-input-4-bf9f2254f869> in <module>()
----> 1 imsave('test.png', W)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.pyc in imsave(name, arr)
    160 
    161     """
--> 162     im = toimage(arr)
    163     im.save(name)
    164     return

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.pyc in toimage(arr, high, low, cmin, cmax, pal, mode, channel_axis)
    235         if mode in [None, 'L', 'P']:
    236             bytedata = bytescale(data,high=high,low=low,cmin=cmin,cmax=cmax)
--> 237             image = Image.frombytes('L',shape,bytedata.tostring())
    238             if pal is not None:
    239                 image.putpalette(asarray(pal,dtype=uint8).tostring())

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in fromstring(mode, size, data, decoder_name, *args)
   1795 
   1796     im = new(mode, size)
-> 1797     im.fromstring(data, decoder_name, args)
   1798     return im
   1799 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in fromstring(self, data, decoder_name, *args)
    589         d = _getdecoder(self.mode, decoder_name, args)
    590         d.setimage(self.im)
--> 591         s = d.decode(data)
    592 
    593         if s[0] >= 0:

OverflowError: size does not fit in an int
```

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace for the error?

Comment: You know you're trying to save a 19GB array as a `.png` file right.

Comment: wow, I'm surprised you can even create that array :)

Comment: He mentioned that it also fails for a 50Kx50K array. Since the data will likely be stored as uint8 in the png, that's really only 2.5 GB (uncompressed). I'm curious if he gets the same result for a 46Kx46K array, which would put the converted data size at just under `2**31` (max size for 32-bit signed int).

Comment: @bogatron, it works when W is 2**16 by 2**14 but fails when the second dimension is 2**15, so it looks like you've identified the problem... that is a strange constraint.